# Is there any way to prevent a privileged program from successfully executing unlink()?

Tags: c, linux, stat, unlink

Assuming a privileged program contains this line of code:

```
unlink("hello.txt");
```

Is there anything that I can do before I run the privileged program so that, even after the unlink() call is made, hello.txt will still exist and lstat() and stat() can still successfully register that it exists?

I was thinking of maybe the possibility of creating symbolic or hard links with the same name so that these links could be unlinked by the unlink() call, leaving the actual hello.txt file untouched. However, I wasn't sure if that was possible.

Comment: You could set up an LD_PRELOAD hack to ignore all or selected `unlink` calls

Comment: seccomp, or chroot, maybe? Are you privileged too?

Comment: Mounting the filesystem as read-only?

Comment: chattr +i maybe? But it's an arms race that ultimately the sysadmin will win... if they have to dismount the filesystem, use a sector editor to nuke the inode, and run fsck to clean up the mess, *they can do that.*

Comment: @thatotherguy what if the command is calling `remove(3)` instead of `unlink(2)`? Or if it `rename(2)`s the file before removing it? Or the process is setugid and ld_preload tricks don't work?

Comment: @Selena You can of course create another *hard* link to the same file, eg. with `link("hello.txt", "hjelp.txt")`, and `hjelp.txt` will stay on after unlinking the original, but there's no guarantee that the privileged program won't seek and destroy it by doing a search for all the directory entries which point to the same inode ;-)

Comment: The chances are, @user414777, that `remove(3)` uses `unlink(2)` — and `rmdir(2)` — and thus ends up being trapped when `unlink(2)` is caught.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it doesn't matter -- if `remove(3)` calls `unlink(2)` internal to the C library, it won't go through the preloaded library. Just like overriding `write(2)` from a preloaded lib won't catch `printf(3)` or `fflush(3)`.

Comment: So you're saying that interposing something to catch `unlink()` doesn't really catch `unlink()`.  I'm not going to argue, @user414777; I've not bothered to investigate.  IMO, interposition is unlikely to work because the administrator won't have the LD_PRELOAD stuff set up the way that is required to make the interposition happen.  Again, I've not investigated — no motive to do so.  The whole process is doomed to failure.  If the system administrator wants that file removed, it will be removed.

Comment: @user414777 I'm not sure what you're getting at. The question is very explicit about the program calling `unlink(2)`.

Comment: @thatotherguy "privileged program" sounds like setuid/set-caps. `LD_PRELOAD` won't work. But if interpreting the Q *that* narrowly, a better answer would be "edit the program and remove the `unlink(2)` call".

Comment: @Selena btw, another way to prevent a file from being removed is to bind-mount another file upon it. The unlink() will fail with EBUSY. `touch foo bar; mount -B foo bar` => `unlink("bar")` will fail.